# Matching hex bytes in hex strings using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

What I have is an input string which represents a hex number, e.g.:

```
E3E4E5E64E
```

I would like to test it, using a regular expression, whether certain hex byte is present
in the number represented by this hex string, e.g.: `4E`.

When I'm trying to simply match `4E`, I'm hitting both the correct `4E` byte at the end of the string and incorrect `4E` which does not form a byte, but is simply the last digit of `E4`
and first digit of `E5`.

Is it possible to write a regular expression to operate on pairs of characters?

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've rewritten the post trying to express what I believe OP meant.

Answer (score 2):

`/([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/g`

I am guessing that you want every 2 hex characters.

http://www.regex101.com/r/nO5qL2

**Edit:**

Ok, I understand now what you want, you want to match the 4E at the end, but not any occurences like 4E from E4E5.
Here it is:
`/^([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})*(4E)/`
The first group is matching 0, 2, 4, .. 2n characters and then it will match the 4E group(not necessary for 4E to be group but it is easier to extract it).
Example:
http://www.regex101.com/r/iQ7uX4

Of course, you can replace 4E with anything you want.
Java RegExp may need a .* at the end of the RegExp, I cannot test right now.

Comment: If you mean to match every 2 characters in a hexadecimal string you'll  need to match characters in the range `a-fA-F`.

Comment: Edited, I am still sleepy :)

Comment: I am not want to match hex characters. Just want match the right hex byte in the hex string.  in the E3E4E5E64E the first 4E is wrong hex string, because it belongs E4 and E5 byte. the last 4E is right hex byte.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as your regex:

```
4E(?=(?:..)*$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?369nh)

`(?=(?:..)*$)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `4E` is only matched if this assertion is true. This assertion is true if there are only multiples of 2 characters `(?:..)*` till the end (ensured with the [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`).

Comment: This does not work:                                               SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('E3E4E5E64E61', '4E(?=(?:..)*)$', '') "REGEXP_REPLACE" FROM test.t1 A;                                              
REGEXP_REPLACE
------------
E3E4E5E64E61

Comment: This question is tagged Java, this looks not like Java! What is not working? Be more specific!

Comment: I use the regular expressions in Java and sql. the sql just for testing.

Comment: Test it in Java. I don't know what kind of regex SQL is using, but I am quite sure it is more limited than Java regexes. There is a good chance that it does not support lookaround assertions.

Comment: I try to you link. 4E(?=(?:..)*)$ just match the last 4E, if the source string is E3E4E5E64E61, will not match the last 4E. Can you modify the pattern, make sure that it will match the right hex byte ?

Comment: Sorry I had the anchor wrong, I corrected the regex and the link, please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
       //Input String
       String str = "4EE4E5E64E";
       String splitArray,pattern="4E";

       //Convert into json Array
       splitArray=Arrays.toString(str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})"));

       //Split based on ","
       String[] tempArray = splitArray.split(",");

       for(int i=0;i<tempArray.length;i++)
       {
           String compareString=tempArray[i];

           //Remove whitespaces
           compareString=compareString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
           if(i==0||(i==tempArray.length-1))
           {
               if(i==0)
               {
                    compareString=compareString.substring(1,3);
               }else
               {
                    compareString=compareString.substring(0,2);
               }
           }  

           //Compare with pattern string If yes goes inside
           if(compareString.equalsIgnoreCase(pattern))
           {
               System.out.println("Yes");   
           }
       }      
    }
}
```

You can also use JSONObject and JSONArray class for spliting an array and comparing with pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are quite limited. They can't "understand" the context.

For more details, read about:

- [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)
- [Chomsky hierarchy of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

So, with standard regular expressions, it is not possible to distinguish between `4E` standing between two hex numbers `E4E5` and one forming the hex byte `4E`.

However, nothing forces you to rely on regexes only! For example, if you know your string contains hex string only, you can accept only those matches resulting from a regexp that start at **even position** indices.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to accept only those matches resulting from a regexp that start at even position indices ?     These is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the regular expression: ([4E]{2}) can fit fine for you...!!